# it seems that has "polls/urls.py " but i dont get what

Tags: django

i dont know why there is bug even it seems not...
i post my githuub.
https://github.com/Angelheartha/tera

in ther termional, i did
python.py shell

later
from django.test import Client

from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()
create an instance of the client for our use
client = Client()
response = client.get(reverse('polls:index'))

the result was this in the end
Internal Server Error: /polls/
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
```

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

i dont understand the problem here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your polls/templates/polls/index.html you have this raw:

```
 <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

Try 'polls:detail' in url tag cause you need to specify namespace for reverse function here